# Java read CSR V3 Extensions

Tags: java, certificate, x509, csr

I generated a certificate signing request (CSR) using the tool https://certificatetools.com/newui/ and now I want to read all the fields including the extensions.

For example, using google.com in the tool as an example, it generates the following CSR:

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: CN = *.google.com, C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e3:b5:a0:d8:........
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.google.com, DNS:*.android.com, DNS:*.appengine.google.com, DNS:*.cloud.google.com, ...............
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         44:a0:41:41:88:66:......
```

Currently, I'm reading the CSR in the following way:

```
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("/..../cert.csr");
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(fileReader);

    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr =
            new PKCS10CertificationRequest(pemReader.readPemObject().getContent());

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
    pemWriter.writeObject(new PemObject("CERTIFICATE REQUEST", csr.getEncoded()));
    pemWriter.flush();
    pemWriter.close();
    String csrPEM = writer.toString();

    System.out.println(csrPEM);
    System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + csr.getSubject().toString());
```

How can I read the rest of the fields (e.g. X509v3 Extended Key Usage)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this the way I am reading CSR details in my java program which works very well. I am reading it for getting user uuid.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(csr);
CertificateRequest p10CertReq = new CertificateRequest(bais);
Name userDN = p10CertReq.getSubject();
String user = userDN.getRFC2253String();
```

`iaik.pkcs.pkcs10.CertificateRequest` object exposes getAttribute method which can be used to retrieve the attributes